# Need help with technical detail in Dedekind's 1872 paper

Tags: number-theory

I found the restatement of Dedekind's construction of real numbers in Rudin quite confusing. As a German speaker, I started to read the paper by Dedekind (1872), which is very beautiful and gives a great intuition for what he is trying to achieve (an English translation of the paper is also available on the internet).

However, Dedekind is a bit too ingenious for me. He constructs a cut that does not correspond to a rational number, and I have technical difficulties with the proof that the cut has this property. Let me list his assumptions and conclusions, in particular the one I don't understand:

(1) He assumes that $D$ is a positive integer which is *not* the square of another integer. Then, he says, there exists another positive integer $\lambda$ such that
$$\lambda^{2} < D < (\lambda + 1)^{2}.$$
This claim can be accepted.

(2) He assumes (by way of contradiction) that $\sqrt{D}$ is a rational number. Then there are positive integers $t,u$ such that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
t^{2} - Du^{2} = 0.
\end{equation}
This is also fine. Moreover, he assumes $u$ to be the smallest positive integer such that for a positive integer $t$ the equation (1) is fulfilled.

(3) From this follows, he argues, that
$$\lambda u < t < (1+\lambda)u,$$
and that the number $u' := t - \lambda u$ is a positive integer which is smaller than $u$. I agree with all of this.

(4) Now, however, he defines a number 
$$t' = Du - \lambda t$$
and claims that $t'$ is a **positive** integer. Here I cannot follow him anymore. I have no idea why $t'$ should be positive. How does this follow from what he has done so far?

Looking forward to hearing the answer to this personal riddle...

Comment: $Du-\lambda t={t\over u}(t-\lambda u)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, John Dawkins. This solves the problem. I was fixated on showing that $Du > \lambda t$, but you just argue that $t'$ is a product of two factors which are both positive. Great! Thank you!